# ServiceLocationProvider must be set

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light. When I add more value converters in my resources my app crashes with exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ServiceLocationProvider must be set.

In the `App.xaml.cs` OnLaunched event I have this line

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
```

It crashes there..
In this ServiceLocator I can see there is a SetLocatorProvider method which takes as an argument ServiceLocatorProvider. I couldnt find anything in the Web and Microsofts MSDN page is dated:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            ...
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            ...
        }

        Window.Current.Activate();

        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
    }
```

EDIT: Here is the full OnLaunched event.
After putting

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

an exception occures:

> An exception of type Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException' occurred in GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type not found in cache: cMC.ViewModel.MyViewModel.

This is the code of ViewModelLocator

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyViewModel>();
    }

    public MyViewModel MyVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup() {}
}
```

Comment: Since the ServiceLocator is some sort of Wrapper for the available IoC Containers like unity or mef ...
It requires you to set the provider by invoking the method ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocatorAdapter(container));

Answer (score 6):

I kinda figured it out.

There was also a need to register the ViewModel, something that happened in the ViewModelLocator constructor, but for some reason the constructor is executed later. So I modified the ViewModelLocator class like this:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {

    }

    public static void SetAndReg()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyViewModel>();
    }

    public MyViewModel MyVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup() {}
}
```

}

Then in the App.xaml.cs:

```
...OnLaunched(...)
{
...
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();

        ViewModelLocator.SetAndReg();

        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModel>();
...
}
```

Comment: Sorry did not see that blunder.
Maybe you might consider not using a SetAndReg method but using a static Constructor?
See my Example above, you can then instatiate this thing in you App.xaml     <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" d:IsDataSource="True" /> and use it in your controls: 
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator},
                                   Path=TestButlerMainWindowViewModel}"
This is supposed to be "cleaner"

Comment: Likely what is happening is the view model locator constructor has yet to be created. So therefore the service locator would not be set. Try using your original code in a different event such as OnWindowCreated and see if that fixes your issue. If you want all of the start up events check out this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.application#events

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the LocationProvider (well the error message is quite obvious..):

You need to give the ServiceLocator your IoC Container of choice:
See this example which uses Unity and an Adapter:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocatorAdapter(container));

        container.RegisterInstance<ILoggingService>(new ConsoleLoggingService());
        container.RegisterInstance<IMessageBoxService>(new SimpleMessageBoxService());
        container.RegisterInstance<ITestSuiteService>(new TestSuiteService());
        container.RegisterInstance<IApplicationService>(new ApplicationService());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="BackstageAboutViewModel"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public BackstageAboutViewModel BackstageAboutViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BackstageAboutViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well in the constructor ViewModelLocator theres a line: "ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);". Isn't it this?  When I copy this in the OnLaunched event in App.cs it booms with an exception telling me that MyViewModel is not found in cache..

Comment: @V.G. You should provide more code than, I was expecting you to not set anything.

Comment: @V.G. your code looks fine from my side.If you did not modify SimpleIoC or something I guess your problem is somewhere else. YOu are posting this error message now: Type not found in cache: cMC.ViewModel.MyViewModel.
Which indicates, that somewhat you TYpe MyViewModel cannot be resolved, are you having some Dependencies there?

Comment: I don' t think so. I created a new clean project, simulating the same problem and the this thing with the cache still pointed to the ViewModel..